# Simple SQL Update Statement Syntax

Tags: php, mysql

Attempting to update a record within my MySQL database with PHP.  I am a PHP noob so I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious.

My new code (update-task.php) - it submits and redirects but the record is not updated.

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'id' => $_POST['id'],
    'TaskName' => $_POST['TaskName'],
    'ClientName' => $_POST['ClientName'],
    'AssignedTo' => $_POST['AssignedTo'],
    'DueDate' => $_POST['DueDate'],
    'TimeLogged' => $_POST['TimeLogged'],
    'Notes' => $_POST['Notes'],
    'Urgent' => $_POST['Urgent']
);

require('mysql.php');
$db = new mysql;
$db->connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_pass;', 'my_db');
$db->query("UPDATE `my_table` SET TaskName='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['TaskName']) . "',
    ClientName='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['ClientName']) . "',
    AssignedTo='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['AssignedTo']) . "',
    DueDate='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['DueDate']) . "',
    TimeLogged='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['TimeLogged']) . "',
    Notes='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['Notes']) . "',
    Urgent='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['Urgent']) . "' WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['id']) . "'
");

header('Location:saved.htm');
```

My form looks like this (view-task.php)

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
require('mysql2.php');
$db = new mysql;
$db->connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_pass;', 'my_db');
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE id = '" . $id ."'");
while($result = $db->fetch_array($query)) {
    $data = $result;
}
?>

<form action="update-task.php" method="post" id="form1" name="form1">

    <label>Task Name:</label>
    <input name="TaskName" type="text" id="TaskName" size="30" value="<?php echo $data['TaskName']?>"/>

    <label>Client</label>
    <input name="ClientName" type="text" id="ClientName" size="30" value="<?php echo $data['ClientName']?>"/>

    <label>Assigned To</label>
    <input name="AssignedTo" type="text" id="AssignedTo" size="30" value="<?php echo $data['AssignedTo']?>"/>

    <label>Due Date</label>
    <input name="DueDate" type="text" id="DueDate" size="30" value="<?php echo $data['DueDate']?>"/>

    <label>Time Logged</label>
    <input type="button" value="Start Count" onClick="timedCount()">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $data['TimeLogged']?>" id="TimeLogged" name="TimeLogged">
    <input type="button" value="Stop Count" onClick="stopCount()">
    <input type="button" value="Clear Timer" onClick="clearTimer()">

    <label>Notes</label>
    <input name="Notes" type="textarea" id="Notes" size="30" value="<?php echo $data['Notes']?>"/>

    <label>Urgent</label>
    <input name="Urgent" type="text" id="Urgent" size="30" value="<?php echo $data['Urgent']?>"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="AddButton">

</form>
```

Contents of mysql.php

```
<?php
class mysql {
    var $querynum = 0;
    var $querylist = '';

    function connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpw, $dbname, $pconnect=0) {
        $die = false;

        if($pconnect) {
            @mysql_pconnect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpw) or ($die = true);
        } else {
            @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpw) or ($die = true);
        }

        if($die) {
            die(mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    function fetch_array($query, $type=MYSQL_ASSOC) {
        $query = mysql_fetch_array($query, $type);
        return $query;
    } 

    function query($sql) {
        $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $this->querynum++;
        $this->querylist .= "$sql <br />";
        return $query;
    }

    function result($query, $row) {
        $query = mysql_result($query, $row);
        return $query;
    }

    function num_rows($query) {
        $query = mysql_num_rows($query);
        return $query;
    }

    function insert_id() {
        $id = mysql_insert_id();
        return $id;
    }

    function fetch_row($query) {
        $query = mysql_fetch_row($query);
        return $query;
    }
    function affected_rows() {
        $query = mysql_affected_rows();
        return $query;
    }
    function close() {
        mysql_close();
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Call class  as `$db = new mysql();`<--

Comment: @Saty I tried this but still get error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES( 0, 'Task 2', 'Client Test', 'Person', '04/14/2017', '0', 'First Task ' at line 1"

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent sql injection and it makes your statement more readable

Comment: Stop using deprecated mysql_ api use mysqli_ or pdo

Comment: Remove the closing bracked steht the end of the update statement

Comment: @Jens I removed a ) from line 23 on update-task.php.  The form now submits and redirects, but the record is not updated.  I updated my original post with the new code.

Comment: Echo out the SQL and check if the values are correct

Comment: Not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating data, so then you have uniq id, post a code from mysql.php
**mysql update query works as `"UPDATE`my_table`SET WHERE id='1'"`.** It looks you have a query error

```
   <?php

$data = array(
    'id' => $_POST['id']
    'TaskName' => $_POST['TaskName'],
    'ClientName' => $_POST['ClientName'],
    'AssignedTo' => $_POST['AssignedTo'],
    'DueDate' => $_POST['DueDate'],
    'TimeLogged' => $_POST['TimeLogged'],
    'Notes' => $_POST['Notes'],
    'Urgent' => $_POST['Urgent']
);

require('mysql.php');
$db = new mysql();
$db->connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_pass;', 'my_db');
$db->query("UPDATE `my_table` SET TaskName='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['TaskName']) . "',
    ClientName='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['ClientName']) . "',
    AssignedTo='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['AssignedTo']) . "',
    DueDate='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['DueDate']) . "',
    TimeLogged='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['TimeLogged']) . "',
    Notes='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['Notes']) . "',
    Urgent='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['Urgent']) . "' WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['id']) . "'
)");
header('Location:saved.htm');

?>
```

form

```
<?php
$data['id'] = $_GET['id'];
require('mysql.php');
$db = new mysql();
$db->connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_pass;', 'my_db');
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE id = '" . $data['id'] ."'");
while($result = $db->fetch_array($query)) {
    $data = array_merge($data, $result);
}
?>


<form action="update-task.php" method="post">

    <label>Task Name:</label>
    <input name="TaskName" type="text" id="TaskName" size="30" value="<?= $data['TaskName']?>"/>

    <label>Client</label>
    <input name="ClientName" type="text" id="ClientName" size="30" value="<?= $data['ClientName']?>"/>

    <label>Assigned To</label>
    <input name="AssignedTo" type="text" id="AssignedTo" size="30" value="<?= $data['AssignedTo']?>"/>

    <label>Due Date</label>
    <input name="DueDate" type="text" id="DueDate" size="30" value="<?= $data['DueDate']?>"/>

    <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?= $data['id']?>"/>

    <label>Time Logged</label>
    <input type="button" value="Start Count" onClick="timedCount()">
    <input type="text" value="<?= $data['TimeLogged']?>" id="TimeLogged" name="TimeLogged">
    <input type="button" value="Stop Count" onClick="stopCount()">
    <input type="button" value="Clear Timer" onClick="clearTimer()">

    <label>Notes</label>
    <input name="Notes" type="textarea" id="Notes" size="30" value="<?= $data['Notes']?>"/>

    <label>Urgent</label>
    <input name="Urgent" type="text" id="Urgent" size="30" value="<?= $data['Urgent']?>"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="AddButton">

</form>
```

Comment: Posted contents of mysql.php  How do I pull in the ID of the current record?

Comment: you can pass your id by url or post $_GET $_POST, if you want to update so then you have a uniq key by which you can update. Queries on how to, you can read in here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: This all sounds good, but I don't know how to implement.  The w3schools link shows a hardcoded ID-  when I view a task I use the following view-task.php?id=1

Comment: your url is "www.example.com?id=2" and code:
$id = $_GET["id"];
$sql = "UPDATE MyGuests SET lastname='Doe' WHERE id=$id";

Comment: I replaced my code with your new version above (thanks!) - I'm now getting the following error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 8"

Comment: check the table names and rows from db, are they same to "ClientName, AssignedTo, DueDate". And if you still have an error, write the page name where the error appears EX: update-task.php
and if you have a white screen, add these two lines, before your code: error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: Error appears on update-task.php - no white screen just the "line 8 error"

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. You need to use `SET` with a `WHERE` clause to identify what to actually update.

SQL update syntax:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: I've seen this reference, however I do not know how to modify my code.  Can you get me started?